# I can ping localhost but not any external server

Tags: ping, cmd.exe

If I type ping `127.0.0.1`, I get the response. However if I type `ping google.com` or any other external website, I get `Request timed out`.

I know something is blocking in my network, but where I should start looking from?

Comment: It seems that you have network issues. Are you connected to the Internet? If so so, are there any firewalls between you and the Internet?

Comment: What happens when you do `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: what type of modem/router do you have?

Comment: @Mothermole1 I'm in a network, and internet works fine. Its because of some firewall rule. I need to tell IT people to disable but I don't know what to ask them to fix this.

Comment: @TD.512 I get the same timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open any web browser, and browse something. If you didn't have access to the web, it means that you have been completely denied from accessing internet. And if can browse the net, it should be the firewall.

Your firewall is configured to block all Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) packets, as a result you can not send ICMP echo request packets to external networks.

Basically, you need to disable this rule in the firewall either the rule is set on your PC or in the server side, well, I don't know.

Have a look.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell where I should look for it? I'm on Windows 7. I followed this but it does not seem to help https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy

Comment: You have followed all the steps in the link you gave, right? And you still couldn't ping? 

It means your network admin block ICMP in their firewall.

Try to tracert www.google.com and see where it goes.

Comment: yes. the tracert shows couple of lines with the internal ip starting with 10, and then a few IP addresses of my network, and then Request time out for the rest.

Comment: So, that should be the issue with the network firewall. :)

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is your "loopback" address. As such, pinging it does not require any packet to actually go out.

There are many possible reasons for not about to ping google.com. e.g.

- your DNS resolution to google.com failed
- your internet gateway is down
- your route is not setup properly
- you use Wi-Fi and your access point is out of range
- your PC is not able to obtain an IP address through DHCP

I think the last one is most likely. Assuming you are using a PC, try starting a Command Prompt and type "ipconfig" and start from there.